# Not applied classes in html-binding block?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework

guys! I have the view in my ionic project, where I can open modal window by clicking on button. The data of this modal loads dynamically from $scope.article.

View template:

```
   <script id="modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-modal-view ng-style="{'max-width': '100%',
        'bottom': '0px', 'left': '0px', 'margin': 'auto',
        'position': 'fixed',
        'right': '0px',
        'top': '0px', 'width': '100%'}">
    <ion-content style="background:url(img/weather-background.jpg) no-repeat; background-size:100%;">
      <div ng-click="closeModal()" style="z-index:999;color:#000;margin:10px 0 0 10px; position: absolute">
        <div style="width:100%;">
          <i class="ion-close-round"></i>
        </div>
        <div style="width:100%;" ng-bind-html="article.modal_content"></div>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-modal-view>
</script>
```

All html data applys correctly, but template classes don't apply to this.

This is my controller:

```
.controller('ArticleCtrl',function($scope, ContentFac, $state,$ionicLoading,$ionicModal){
  $scope.article = {};
  $ionicLoading.show({
    template: '<ion-spinner icon="android"></ion-spinner>'
  });
  $scope.openModal = function(template){
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(template, {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'slide-in-up',
    }).then(function(modal) {
      $scope.modal = modal;
      $scope.modal.show();
    })
  };
  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };
  // Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $scope.modal.remove();
  });

  $scope.$on('$ionicView.loaded',function(){
    ContentFac.getArticle($state.params.item).then(function(data){
      $scope.$broadcast('fadeContent');
      console.log(data);
      $scope.article = data;
      // $ionicLoading.hide();
    })
  });
  $scope.gotoLink  = function(url){
    window.open(url,'_system');
  }
})
```

For example, I had the same modal in another view, where html data were inserted directly in template, in this way all template classes applied.
What is the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that ng-bind-html doesn't compile tag's attribute 'id', so we can't  apply any styles to it, but attribute 'class' can be applied

Answer (score 0):

May be ?

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
 $scope.article = data;
});
```

OR (if $digest is in progress)

```
$scope.$evalAsync(function () {
   $scope.article = data;
});
```

Comment: I think you should mention that your answer is based on ES6